# Berkshelf and mysql

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, knife, recipe

I edited Berksfile like this,

```
site :opscode
cookbook 'php-fpm'
cookbook 'yum-epel'
cookbook 'mysql'
```

and run `berks install`, then edit `foo.json` like this.

```
{"run_list": [
    "recipe[yum-epel]",
    "recipe[php-fpm]",
    "recipe[mysql]"
]}
```

And I get this `RecipeNotFound`, when I run `knife solo cook foo`.

```
Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe default for cookbook mysql
```

As the error indicate there is no `default.rb` in `cookbooks/mysql/recipes/`.

I thought Berkshelf creates the `default.rb` from opscode site automatically that didn't happen.

What should I do to use opscode mysql recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to choose `"recipe[mysql::server]"` or `"recipe[mysql::client]"`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: That was the exact answer that I needed.